# solve $h = 36\sin(1.5t) - 15\cos(1.5t) + 65$ using $k\sin(1.5t - \alpha)$

Tags: trigonometry

> The blades of a turbine are turning at a steady rate.
>
> The height $h$ metres, of the tip of one of the blades above the
>   ground at time, $t$ seconds is given by the formula:
>
> $h = 36\sin(1.5t) - 15\cos(1.5t) + 65$
>
> Express $36\sin(1.5t) - 15\cos(1.5t)$ in the form $k\sin(1.5t -
> > \alpha)$ where $k>0$ and $0<\alpha < \frac{\pi}2$
>   and hence find the two values of t for which the tip of this blade is
>   at a height of 100 metres above the ground during the first turn.

$36\sin(1.5t) - 15\cos(1.5t) = k\sin(1.5t -\alpha)$

$36\sin(1.5t) - 15\cos(1.5t) = k\cos\alpha\sin 1.5 t - k\sin\alpha\cos 1.5t$

$k\cos \alpha = 36$

$k\sin \alpha = -15$

$\alpha = \arctan\frac{-15}{36} = -22.6$

$\alpha$ is in the 4th quadrant because $\sin$ is negative and $\cos$ is positive.

$k = \sqrt{15^2 + 36^2} = 39$

$\therefore 39\sin(1.5t - 337.4) = -65$

$39\sin(1.5t - 337.4) = -65$

$\sin(1.5t - 337.4) = \frac{-65}{39}$

Which is where I am stuck because $\arcsin\frac{-65}{39}$ is undefined.

Comment: You found another way of expressing $36\sin1.5t-15\cos1.5t$. You also found that if you then put $h=0$ there is no value of $t$ for which that is true. That is unsurprising. Incidentally, the question expresses $\alpha$ in radians, so it is probably better to take it as $-0.3948$ rather than $337.4^o$.

Comment: By the way ksina=15 not -15.

Comment: @PrayasAgrawal of course, missed the double minus

Comment: @almagest of course, radians is the correct way

Comment: @dagda1 So I do not understand what your problem is. You have successfully found that $h=39\sin(1.5t-0.3948)+65$.

Comment: @almagest actually I do not because I would still need to find $\arcsin\frac{-65}{39}$ which would be undefined or am I missing something?

Comment: Why do you need to find $\sin^{-1}-\frac{65}{39}$?

Comment: In order to solve $39\sin(1.5t - 337.4) = -65$, I would need to get rid of $\sin$ to isolate t by taking the arcsin of both sides

Comment: @dagda1 You dont "have" to solve the equation at all( forget about solving it at zero).

Comment: @PrayasAgrawal apologies, I left out part of the question, I have updated the question

Comment: @dagda1 You want to solve $h=100$. You found that $h=39\sin(1.5t-0.3948)+65$, so $\sin(1.5t-0.3948)=\frac{35}{39}$. That is easy to solve.

Comment: why $\frac{35}{39}$ and not $\frac{-65}{39}$

Comment: sorry but where does $h=100$ come from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $36\sin(1.5t) - 15\cos(1.5t) = k\cos\alpha\sin 1.5 t - k\sin\alpha\cos 1.5t$
>
> $k\cos \alpha = 36$
>
> $k\sin \alpha = -15$

This is incorrect. We have $$-k\sin\alpha=-15\quad\Rightarrow\quad k\sin\alpha=\color{red}{+}15$$
and so we have $\alpha=\arctan(15/36)\approx 0.395$ satisfying $0\lt \alpha\lt \pi/2$.

> $\therefore 39\sin(1.5t - 337.4) = -65$

We have $$h=39\sin(1.5t-0.395)+65.$$

However, we **cannot** write this as
$$39\sin(1.5t-0.395)=-65\tag1$$
because $(1)$ is equivalent to $39\sin(1.5t-0.395)+65=0$, i.e. $h=0$ which we don't have.

Now, $h=100$ comes from the question itself saying "find the two values of t for which the tip of this blade is at a height of 100 metres above the ground during the first turn".

It follows from these that
$$100=h=39\sin(1.5t-0.395)+65,$$
i.e.
$$39\sin(1.5t-0.395)=100-65=35$$
Dividing the both sides by $39$ gives
$$\sin(1.5t-0.395)=\frac{35}{39}$$
This is how we have $35/39$ as almagest has shown in comments.

$\qquad\qquad\qquad$[image]

Finally, since $t\gt 0\Rightarrow 1.5t-0.395\gt -0.395=-\alpha$, we solve
$$1.5t-0.395=\arcsin\frac{35}{39}\quad\text{or}\quad \pi-\arcsin\frac{35}{39}$$
and the answer is $\color{red}{t\approx 1.006\quad\text{or}\quad 1.615}$.

Answer (score 2):

Following the OP's steps, we want to rewrite the given expression in another form.

$$ 36 \sin(1.5 t) - 15 \cos(1.5 t) = 39 \left( \frac{12}{13} \sin(1.5 t) - \frac{5}{13} \cos(1.5 t) \right) $$

Now, defining an angle $ \alpha $ such that $ \sin(\alpha) = 5/13 $ and $\cos(\alpha) = 12/13 $, we have that

$$ = 39 \sin(1.5t - \alpha) $$

as desired. (Factoring 39 out was necessary because we need to have $ \sin^2 (\alpha) + \cos^2 (\alpha) = 1 $, which is now satisfied.)

The question asks us to find the solutions of $ h(t) = 100 $, or $ 39 \sin(1.5t - \alpha) = 35 $. Using a calculator, we can find an approximate value for $ \alpha $:

$$ \alpha = \arcsin \left(\frac{5}{13} \right) \approx 0.394 $$

so that we have to solve $ \sin(1.5 t - 0.394) = 35/39 $. Then, one solution is

$$ 1.5t - 0.394 = \arcsin \left(\frac{35}{39} \right) \approx 1.114 $$

or $ t \approx 1.005 $. Now, recall that $ \sin(x) = \sin(\pi - x) $ to find the second solution:

$$ 1.5t - 0.394 = \pi - 1.114 \approx 2.027 $$

which yields $ t \approx 1.614 $.

Answer (score -2):

k=39

α =-0.394 in radians

h=39sin(1.5t+0.394) + 65

for 100 m

100 = 39sin(1.5t+0.394) + 65

39sin(1.5t+0.394) = 35

sin(1.5t+0.394) = 35/39

t = {arcsin(35/39) - 0.394 } / 1.5

t = ( 1.113-0.394) / 1.5

t = 0.719 sec

and other value in π−1.113 = 3.14 - 1.113 = 2.027

t = ( 2.027 - 0.394 ) / 1.5 
t = 1.088 sec